# Python - selecting range of values in ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have imported a .wav file into Python with `wavfile.read` and am using the frequency data to do an intensity -vs- frequency plot (with Fast Fourier Transforms).

Now I'm trying to isolate and plot certain frequency ranges. I can't seem to extract the index values from the `array` vector in order to identify the corresponding intensity values.

I have tried `revel` and `flatten` on the frequency vector but I still get the `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'` error. Is my `array` actually an `ndarray`? If so, how could I resolve this?

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# enter directory of .wav file here:
directory = 'C:\'

# import .wav file
fs, samples = wavfile.read(str(directory)) # fs = sample rate
y = samples / np.linalg.norm(samples) # normalised sample values
t = np.arange(0,len(y))/fs # make time vector

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.title('my waveform')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')

# power spectrum
powSpec = np.abs(np.fft.fft(y))**2
time_step = 1 / fs
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y), time_step) # find frequency
idx = np.argsort(freq)
plt.figure(1)
f = freq[idx] # frequencies
ps = powSpec[idx] # power spectrum
plt.plot(f, ps)
plt.xlim(-2000, 2000)
plt.title('power spectrum')
plt.xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('power')
plt.show()

# remove freq components

def find_nearest(array, value):
    # function to extract frequency values and position in array
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

book = np.array([1,2,4,8,16,32,64]) # selecting orders of resonant frequencies
fnote = np.ndarray.ravel(f)

for n in book:
    f_mid = find_nearest(f, 523.25*n)
    f_low = find_nearest(f-25, 523.25*n-25)
    f_hi = find_nearest(f+25, 523.25*n+25)
    #print (fnote_low,fnote_mid,fnote_hi)
    print (fnote.index(f_mid))
```

---

As @desired login suggested, I changed the `print (fnote.index(f_mid))` line to `print (np.where(fnote==f_low),np.where(fnote==f_mid),np.where(fnote==f_hi))` and I get

```
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([97065], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([99315], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([103815], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([112815], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([130815], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([166814], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
((array([], dtype=int64),), (array([189629], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),))
sample rate fs = 44100
Nyqvist frequency fn = 22050.0
```

Why am I getting `[]`?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: What is the shape of your array, and what range of indices do you wish to extract?

Comment: you might be looking for [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). `print (np.where(fnote==f_mid))`